# Why an else if clause results in a "this condition will always return 'true'" error?

Tags: typescript, logic, control-flow

One of the topics in the handbook basics is that TypeScript catches logic errors. I changed the `else if` clause of the `if...else` statement from the [example in the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#non-exception-failures) to the following:

```
const value = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b";
if (value !== "a") {

} else if (value !== "b") {
    
}
```

But got an error:

> "This condition will always return 'true' since the types '"a"' and '"b"' have no overlap."

What I am missing? Also, it worked in JavaScript, so why is it not working in TypeScript?

Comment: You don't need the second `if` since there are only two possible options

Comment: I know I don't need a second if but why it looks like an error so I was confused. Typescript is saving me from writing more codes so it is showing as an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of control flow analysis and type narrowing.

Typescript will initially type `value` as `"a" | "b"`. The  `value !== "a"` check means that on the true branch `value` will be `"b"` and  so it will type value as only `"b"`, on the false branch it will be typed as `"a"`, since anything else would have entered the true branch.

This means that you are checking something which will always be true (`value !== b`, is always true since `value` is `"a"`), and typescript will warn you about it.